# NSDate() convert to string

Tags: string, swift, nsdate

```
let startDate=NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-60*60*24)
let endDate=NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*24*3)

lblStart.text = i.startDate
```

I want the startdate show in a label. How can I convert it to a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332946/nsdateformatter-stringfromdatensdate-returns-empty-string

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/nsdate/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to NSDate with Swift 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058091/convert-string-to-nsdate-with-swift-2)

Comment: That isn't the right way to add/subtract days either. You should use NSDateComponents. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197994/how-i-can-get-the-nsdate-of-yesterday. Simply adding/subtracting seconds won't work across daylight savings time changes

Answer (score 0):

You can try `lblStart.text = "\(i.startDate)"`

To convert a variable to a string or get its value to output onto a label you would do this: `"\(variable name)"`